# Showing pdf in Access form gets stuck on initializing screen

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to display a pdf file in an Access form, but my code only works once. When I close the Access application and reopen it Acropdf doesn't display the pdf, it just gets stuck on this screen:

[image]

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim strPdfDoc As String
    'Below is my source
    strPdfDoc = "F:\Grifols\files\Unified Region TemplateV1_0_Budget.pdf"
    'Here I am loading the pdf file with Acropdf 
    AcroPDF0.loadFile strPdfDoc
End Sub
```

I get no errors when debugging the code, but the pdf never shows.

Comment: My question is that i am using Acropdf for displaying pdf in access form.My code works only for one time when i create new application on access but when i close this application and reopen it it didnt works.

Comment: If you paid for a license to this product you could open a ticket with their support. http://www.acropdf.com/support.html

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue for a long time, it was only happening when the EXE was run as Administrator.

My fix was the following:

1. Set EXE compile to x86 CPU
2. Change PDF output path to ProgramData: "C:\ProgramData(Client)(Project)"
3. Update code to first call "AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(PDFfilepath)" then call "AxAcroPDF1.src = PDFfilepath"

Important: If you need to run the application on Windows Server for some reason, then the 32bit version of Crystal Runtime needs to be installed

Comment: This answer basically has the key -- the app must be compiled to target x86 ONLY.  My application is working and implements both #1 & #2 only.  It works perfectly fine for my, by only calling the LoadFile() method and does not need to use the '.src' property as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your version of Adobe Reader is up to date and replace your code with this. I was able to load the file several times, close and reopen and load again.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim pdf As AcroPDF
    Set pdf = Me.AcroPDF0.Object
    pdf.LoadFile "F:\Grifols\files\Unified Region TemplateV1_0_Budget.pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: My version of adobe is 11.0.10 and it is up to date but still it works only for one time when i close access and reopen access application it show only black screen in AcroAdobe control area.

Comment: its not working still.only black screen appear with initialize label in it on my access form.

Comment: And my office version is office 2010 64bits

Comment: OK, this may sound crazy, but I get the same error when I tried to load your file because it doesn't exist on my computer. Check the file name you are trying to load, it doesn't error out if it can't find it, it just stays black.

Comment: i also verify file path it is correct but control still showing black screen i dnt know why

Answer (score 0):

I had Acrobat Reader DC installed, I Downgraded to 11 from this link
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/install-reader-x-windows.html

And changed the following registry setting to get this to work

To disable the Enable Protected Mode at startup configuration, navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\Privledged

… then modify the bProtectedMode REG_DWORD value to 0 to disable and 1 to enable:

found it at this link 
http://terenceluk.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/disabling-enable-protected-mode-at.html

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, that work for me, at [this link](http://www.efferen.nl/2012/03/solved-adobe-reader-x-hangs-after-opening-a-pdf-file/):

To solve initializing screen for Acrobat Reader XI, just disable "Enable Protected Mode At Startup"

Comment: Don't provide only a link.